# Why DataBinding doesn't work on second time around?

Tags: c#, excel, data-binding, oledb

My code below search for a record in excel based on a textbox text and bind it to a datagrid. but if I tried searching for the same value and bind it again I got error " DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings." any idea how to reset the binding ? I tries formattingEnables set to true it didn't work. thank you

```
OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(_econnect);
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

        connExcel.Open();
        DataTable dt;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dt = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        string sheetname = "BadgeID$";
        cmdExcel.CommandText = "select ID, Name, Dept from [" + sheetname + "] where ID in (" + sss +")";
        da.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        da.Fill(ds);
        connExcel.Close();

       bsdata .DataSource = ds.Tables [0]; //error here
       Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsdata, "Name")));
       Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsdata, "Dept")));
```

Comment: if you but a breakpoint on the second line in this part of your code `da.Fill(ds); connExcel.Close();` what do you see in ds when you evaluate `ds` when you goto QuickWatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call DataBindings.Clear() for each of your textbox

Comment: I think we all get stuck on something like that at least once.